# Running Scrapy spider from a script with scrapy arguments

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a spider in scrapy & I'm successfully able to run it via a python script.
The problem is, while running a spider via scrapy prompt we supply agruments like " -o ScrapedData.json -t json "
I want to run "scrapy crawl myspider ***-o ScrapedData.json -t json*** "  via python script.
Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure if I get your question right, but you probably might want to have a look at the python `subprocess` module.

Answer (score 0):

- `-o ScrapedData.json` overrides the `FEED_URI` setting
- and `-t json` overrides the `FEED_FORMAT` setting

(See https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/commands/crawl.py#L24)

So, when running your spider from a script, you should look at overriding these 2 settings.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```
from scrapy import cmdline

cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl myspider -o ScrapedData.json -t json".split())
```